# Multiple choice: $S = {x | 0 ≤ x < 280 ∧ x ≡ 3 (mod 7) ∧ x ≡ 4 (mod 8)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

**The question is:**

Consider the following set of integers:

$$ S = \left\{x \left| 0 \le x < 280
                       ∧ x \equiv 3 \mod 7
                       ∧ x \equiv 4 \mod 8 \right. \right\}. $$

How many integers are there in S?

$0$? $1$? $2$? $5$? $10$? $280$?

- It's a multiple choice answer with the correct answer of **5**. I just can't seem to wrap around the idea.

Comment: On Math SE we prefer not having thanks sprinkled throughout a question, to keep questions tidy to save readers' time. Also, you should show what you have tried so that we can give appropriate guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$ is equivalent to $x+4 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$.

$x \equiv 4 \pmod{8}$ is equivalent to $x+4 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$.

Thus we want to know which numbers $x$ are such that $x+4$ is divisible by both $7$ and $8$. Since $7$ and $8$ are coprime, it would be exactly those numbers such that $x+4$ is divisible by $7 \times 8 = 56$. You can count easily now.

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the given system of congruences has a unique solution modulo $56$.  (The solution happens to be $x\equiv -4\equiv 52\pmod{56}$, but we don't need to know that.)

Since $280=5\cdot 56$, the system of congruences has $5$ solutions modulo $280$. (They are $x\equiv 52+56k\pmod{280}$, where $k$ ranges from $0$ to $4$.)